# Change Distribution Logo in KinfoCenter

Tags: kde, custom-distributions

I am trying to make a Ubuntu based distribution running KDE Desktop. I wish to modify the logo shown in Kinfocenter with my own distribution's logo. However I cannot find a script in /etc for kinfocenter and I have been trying to find a lot at different places but cannot find. I also downloaded sources, but was unable to find. I am using Plasma 5.10.4. Can someone tell where is the logo residing?

Answer (score 3):

**KInfocenter - Information About This System**

KDE git: https://cgit.kde.org/kinfocenter.git/

For  the customization the about-distro module is reading information from the kcm-about-distrorc configuration file.

kinfocenter/Modules/about-distro/README:

> See example/*.
>
> Essentially you place an rc file in the file system that defines the
>   distro logo and website url. The file ought to be in some
>   XDG_CONFIG_DIRS dir.
>
> e.g. pkexec cp `pwd`/example/kcm-about-distrorc.ex
>   /etc/xdg/kcm-about-distrorc

XDG Base Directory Specification: https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

kinfocenter/Modules/about-distro/example/kcm-about-distrorc.ex

```
[General]
LogoPath=/home/me/kubuntu-circle-small.png
Website=http://www.kubuntu.org
Version=1.2.3
Variant=Unstable Branches
```

Example S.H.A.D.O
($HOME/.config/kcm-about-distrorc as the users configuration files take precedence over system entries of /etc/xdg/kcm-about-distrorc)

```
[General]
Name=S.H.A.D.O
LogoPath=/usr/share/about-distro/SHADO-logo.png
Website=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_(TV_series)#SHADO
Version=123
Variant=Secret
```

KInfocenter will show:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! Would you also help me in this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972487/modify-lsb-release-file-for-my-own-distro ? Thanks again!