# Kubuntu About info has http link, should be https

Tags: kubuntu, security

I was irritated to find a http link in such a prominent location as the "About" info of Kubuntu. This issue persists with the most recent stable release 18.10.

Is there an existing ticket for this problem? Plans to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 3):

The website link is coming from the kubuntu-settings-desktop package as /etc/xdg/kcm-about-distrorc:

```
[General]
LogoPath=/usr/share/kubuntu-default-settings/kubuntu-circle-128.png
Website=http://www.kubuntu.org
Name=Kubuntu
```

You could file a bug report against the kubuntu-settings package. Current bug reports: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/+bugs .

**EDIT ON**

Fixed with the 19.04: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/1:19.04ubuntu1

As told: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74868-http-still-being-used?p=423778#post423778

**EDIT OFF**

If you want to edit the KInfoCenter output in your system: An example from the AskUbuntu - [Change Distribution Logo in KinfoCenter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945531/change-distribution-logo-in-kinfocenter)